# How to convert step size to decimal precision?

Tags: calculus

I want to round values to a certain decimal precision in the format of an unsigned integer. I have a rounding function like

```
round(value, precision)
```

at hand, that I can use.

But I only have a step size like 0.1, 0.2 or 0.01 given. How can I convert it to the decimal precision?

Comment: Is this a math question, or a software question?

Comment: Well, the internals of function don't matter, as they are given. I want to write a function to convert the step size to decimal precision and I need an algorithm. I can write the function once I understand the math, so imo it is a math question.

Comment: There are probably easy solutions for this online, but I am lacking the skills to express it in the right mathematical terms. So I can't find anything...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is going to depend on the function and what *precision* means.  For example in `round(45.6789,2)` giving `45.68` to $2$ decimal places, you have $0.01=10^{-2}$ and $2=-\log_{10}(0.01)=-\log_e(0.01)/\log_e(10)$

Comment: So I guess ``ceil( log( step ) * -1 ) ``is what I am looking for

Comment: Is there something that I can improve about the question to make it understandable or more correct?

Comment: You could put some numerical examples in, to help explain what you are asking for.  Note that for many computers $\log$ is $\log_e$ while for calculators it is often $\log_{10}$

Comment: If you want one decimal place of precision, you would use `round(value, 0.1)`. If you want two decimal places of precision, you would use `round(value, 0.01)`. If you want three decimal places of precision you would use `round(value, 0.001)`. Do you see the pattern?